# AWS ApiGateway Custom authorization with Firebase

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I will explain my use case. I have a web app. First, the app attempts to login to firebase and it gets back a token. I want to use the token issued by firebase to access lambda function through api gateway. Is there a mechanism to validate Firebase tokens in AWS ApiGateway?

[image: design doc]

Comment: Hi @Supun Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: @RE350 I used aws Cognito instead of firebase

Comment: Ohh, Ok, was there any reason from switching from Firebase to Cognito?

Comment: @RE350 we can use aws amplify. it handles authentication

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to write custom Authorizers lambda function for validate your firebase tokens.

This lambda function hit before execute your lambda function.

following diagram explain how it's work

[image]

For write custom  Authorizers function follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) reference. For token validation you can use firebase sdk and its references.

Comment: Just out of curiosity Is firebase auth better with client sdk or nodejs sdk. What should be used when?