# Is this AWS + Firebase Cloud Architecture secure enough?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, authentication, aws-lambda, token

Is this AWS + Firebase Cloud Architecture secure enough?

Overview: User has already signed in and after sign in they can add content that sends a request to API Gateway with an API Key, that then calls the Lambda, the Lambda will only execute if the passed in Firebase Token has been successfully validated. Is this enough or do I need to use the API Gateway Authorizer or other options to help make it more secure? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: this is a hypothetical, merely opinion-based question, because a concept can be outstanding, but when the implementation is poor, this is nothing one could consider as "secure" ...while security does not really exist; but is only measured by likeliness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By letting the api-gw do the auth validation you will get a clearer separation of security in your architecture as your app grows.

I'd rather have a custom lambda authorizer connected to the API-GW and separate from the actual service-lambda as described in the answers here:

[AWS ApiGateway Custom athorization with firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005195/aws-apigateway-custom-athorization-with-firebase)